# Linux permission issue

Tags: sudo

I am using Ubuntu Linux and am new to Linux.  When I try to try to edit some files it requires root privileges.

Following command gives a permission error:

```
echo "xyz" > abc.txt
```

But using `sudo echo "xyz" > abc.txt`  works

I want to do the same thing from UI.  So how can I do it?

Also some files like `hosts` and `hostname` cannot be edited.  Any clues on this? I guess they are read only.  How can i make them writable?

Comment: I can guess some reasons for the downvotes, but the poster has a legitimate (if naive and/or off-topic) question. If you feel the need to downvote it, please add some constructive criticism in a comment so they can ask better questions next time.

Comment: I don't believe it.  If `echo "xyz" > abc.txt` fails, `sudo echo "xyz" > abc.txt` will also fail

Answer (score 1):

The files appear as read-only because you don't have enough permissions to modify them. If you want to use the GUI, you run your editor from command prompt like:

```
sudo gedit
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is necessarily a serverFault topic, more like superuser...but you should be able to change permissions via chmod.

I'm assuming you're the file owner, in which case

```
sudo chmod u=rwx
```

MIGHT (emphasis on the might) work to give you permission to mess with the file outside of sudo.  the u+rwx specifies that the 'user'(owner) of the file gets the r, w, and x permissions (read write execute).

I'm by no means a linux expert, but that seems like it should work.  If you require more help, superuser would be the better stack exchange site to ask on, as serverfault is more for server  issues.